# Aptana svn: opposite of commit?

Tags: svn, aptana

When I want to send my new files from localhost to the remote server, I right click on the project > Team > Commit.

When I want to "sync back" the changes from remote to local (so remote files are newer) I try right click on the project > Team > Update, but this does not work.

How can I sync my files from remote > local?

EDIT: to whoever is downvoting - when I visit the Aptana homepage try to find support, there is a link to community discussions which points to SO. They seem to change their community discussion all the time (first tenderapp, now this) and it blows but this is still the only way to get community support!

Answer (score 0):

Just right click in the file you want to get -> Team -> Show History

Here's a Guide to Install SVN in Aptana 3 (but is in spanish though but translate.google.com will help you :) )
http://www.aichholzer.name/item/instalando-svn-en-aptana-studio-3/

Comment: SVN is already installed. Show history is the opposite of Commit?

Answer (score -1):

`Check Out` will get you the latest from Server to Local

Comment: Where in Aptana can I find this? I have a feeling it's called something different.

Comment: Client is Aptana with SVN plugin